# Javascript get all files minus certain file extentions

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I have a script that returns all the files contained within a folder. However, there are some file types in there that I do not want my script to do anything with. I just want it to literally skip over it as if it wasn't there and only deal with the other file types.

How can I achieve this?

So far this is how I'm getting all the files contained within a folder:

```
var samplesFolder = Folder(Path)
//Get the files 
var fileList = samplesFolder.getFiles()
//Creat Array to hold names
var renderTypes = new Array();
//Parse Initial name to get similar render elements
var beautyRender = fileList[0].name
beautyRender = beautyRender.substr(0, beautyRender.length-4)


//Get the render elements with a similar name
for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++)
{
    if(fileList[i].name.substring(0,beautyRender.length) === beautyRender)
    {
            renderTypes[i] = fileList[i].name  
    }

 }
```

This is not used for web purposes I should hasten to add.

*edit*

Above is the complete code I have to get all the image files in a folder and bring them into photoshop once the user has selected the folder they want to use. At the moment it is bringing in every single image in the folder when there is a single type I want it to ignore.

Comment: Yes that is javascript. It is the code I have to get all the files contained with in a folder that the user needs to locate on their computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming fileList is just an array of strings you could do something along the lines of:

```
for (var i = 0, len = fileList.length; i < len; i++) {
    var filename = fileList[i].name;
    if (filename.match(/\.(txt|html|gif)$/i) !== null) { continue; }
    // Your logic here
}
```

Where `txt`, `html` and `gif` are file extensions you want to skip over, you can add more by separating them with `|`

Comment: Tried this but I get an error telling me filename.match isn't a function

Comment: Sounds like `fileList` isn't an array of strings then. What library are you using to return this list of files from a directory? You'll probably have to swap the 2nd line with something along the lines of `var filename = fileList[i].filename;` but I can't be sure without knowing whats contained in `fileList`

Comment: Looks like you'll want to change line #2 to `var filename = fileList[i].name;` looking at page 50 of the following PDF: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/scripting/pdfs/javascript_tools_guide.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the list and only collect those with extensions you care about. i see [photoshop](/questions/tagged/photoshop) so I'll assume image files only:

```
var distilledFileList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
  if (/\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif|psd)$/i.test(fileList[i].name)){
    distilledFileList.push(fileList[i]);
  }
}
```

Now `distilledFileList` contains only `*.jpg`, `*.jpeg`, `*.png`, `*.gif`, and `*.psd` files.

if you want an easier (more readable) way to check extensions (maybe you're not as fluent as regular expressions):

```
// fileList = ....

// setup an array of bad extensions here:
var bad = ['txt', 'log', 'db'],
    // holds new list of files that are acceptable
    distilledFileList = [];

// iterate over entire list
for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
  // grab the file extenion (if one exists)
  var m = fileList[i].name.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/);
  // if there is an extenions, make sure it's now in the
  // 'bad' list:
  if (m && bad.indexOf(m[1].toLowerCase()) != -1){
    // it's safe, so add it to the distilled list
    distilledFileList.push(fileList[is]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I could do it so it ignores the only file extension I don't want? There are less files extensions I don't want than those I do.

Comment: @N0xus: Sure, use `if (!(/\.(?:ext1|ext2|ext3)$/i.test(fileList[i])){` instead so it negates the test.