# Importing images with only specific file extension into Photoshop

Tags: javascript, import, photoshop

I am new to JavaScripting (have learned allot from this site!). I have existing code (from someone else) that successfully brings in all images into photoshop from a user selected folder. I would like to modify the code to only bring in specific file extensions (Jpg, png, tiff...etc). I found a great example of code from this site below of what I would like to do.

```
var distilledFileList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
  if (/\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif|psd)$/i.test(fileList[i].name)){
    distilledFileList.push(fileList[i]);
  }
}
```

[Original code found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19657909/javascript-get-all-files-minus-certain-file-extentions)

I have not figured out how to implement a version of this successfully into what I already have. Here is the main section of my code I believe where the modification needs to be added.

```
    #target photoshop
    app.bringToFront();

    // Dialog for user to choose folder of documents to process
    var inputFolderArray = [];
    do {
    var inputFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Select a folder of documents to process");
    if(inputFolder != null) {
          inputFolderArray.push(inputFolder);
        }
    }

    while(inputFolder != null 
    || inputFolder != undefined)

    // Pulls images from inputFolder
    for (var j = 0; j < inputFolderArray.length; j++) { 
    var filesList = inputFolderArray[j].getFiles();
    var outputDirectory = inputFolderArray[j] + '/';
    }

function PSDCreate(frameArrays, outputDirectory) {
  directory = outputDirectory + '/';

//var outputLocation = inputFolder + "/" + directory;
  var outputFileName = '';

  if (frameArrays != null) {


// Get all the files in the folder
    var fileList = frameArrays;
    var k = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
      if (fileList[i] instanceof File && fileList[i].hidden == false) {

var fileName = fileList[i].name;
        var docRef = open(fileList[i]);

        if(k == 0) {
          k++;
          outputFileName = RemoveExtension(docRef.name);
app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO;
        }
      }
    }


    // Execute changes to images in photoshop here..
```

Does someone know how to implement a version of the example code to what I already have by chance? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add an `If`statement checking the extension of `fileName` before you open the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want user to select several folders and than process files of all these folders. First of all, here

```
// Pulls images from inputFolder
for (var j = 0; j < inputFolderArray.length; j++) { 
    var filesList = inputFolderArray[j].getFiles();
    var outputDirectory = inputFolderArray[j] + '/';
}
```

`filesList` will be overwritten with every new folder, you'll get a list of files from the last folder selected only. I'd change this to

```
// Pulls images from inputFolder
var files = []
for (var j = 0; j < inputFolderArray.length; j++)
{
    var filesList = inputFolderArray[j].getFiles();

    for (var i = 0; i < filesList.length; i++)
    {
        if (/\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif|psd)$/i.test(filesList[i].name)) files.push(filesList[i]); //get needed files from folders
    }
}
alert(files); // < array of files
```

if you only need to open these files, you can replace `files.push(filesList[i]);` with `app.open(fileList[i]);`